# Significance of specific usage of greek letters in math

Tags: optimization, notation

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares

[image]

I understand that Beta  here is a variable, but I was wondering what the significance of using the greek letter beta here (instead of x or some other greek letter).   I think it has something to do with linear correlation coefficients, but not sure.

Citations appreciated.

Also, is there a good general resource for finding the significance of greek letter usage in a formula?  I find knowing these can often given hints as to what the formula does and how it works.

Comment: The general answer to your question is that there is no more *mathematical* significance to the choice of a specific Greek letter than there is to a specific Roman letter (or to a specific letter from other alphabets). Sometimes there's just not enough letters in one alphabet; fortunately there are others to choose from.

Comment: What *human* significance there is to a specific letter in a specific mathematical context is, on the other hand, often historical, traditional, or simply personal.

Comment: Yes...  it is historical and traditional.  The question is, what is the history and tradition of chosing beta for this particular formula.

As I mentioned in the question, at the top, Beta here is a variable, or I guess argument to be minimized.  What's not obvious is the significance of chosing Beta.

Comment: I believe it's pretty typical to use greek letters like $\beta$ or $\theta$ for "hyperparameters" that we can tune, reserving $x$ for a function input.